# Swagger documentation for conditionally required

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to document my java APIs using Swagger plugin in gradle with : "compile "io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.0".
I am using @ApiModelProperty annotation to achieve attribute's description, in my static html document.

I have a common DTO for multiple projects to use, but the problem is that, in some projects a particular attribute is required, but for other projects, its not required. So, I am looking to put some condition for attribute based on other attribute in that same package.

Comment: We had the same problem on my project. We manage this by creating a second DTO extending the first DTO with @ NotNull annotation.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Gremi64 . But for that, I would need to duplicate code, which I am trying to save here. I need to use the attribute at 5 to 10 different places in other projects. In some they are required and in others they are not. If I will extend it each time, it will be having lots of duplicate code.

I am trying to find solution without changing my DTO structure. If some condition I can put through annotations or if any other tool is available to achieve this.

Comment: It's not "duplicate code", we just override getter with the @ NotNull annotation and we call the super.getter.
If you find another solution, please, put it here :)